# Ubuntu 22.04 - Laptop screen is not display but external monitor does

Tags: nvidia, display, 22.04, amd-processor

Ever since I enabled mirroring with my monitor. My laptop doesn't display on its own unless it's connected to my external monitor.
In the settings, I don't see "Display" option. But I only see "Screen Display".
[Here's the screenshot of the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2idU.png)

Any tips on how I can "un-mirror". I'd like to use laptop when it's disconnected. Apology for the noob question.

Comment: What laptop is it?

Comment: It's ASUS ROG Zephyrus G14

Comment: Have you tried function keys to change the display output? I think it’s fn-f9 for that laptop based on a picture I found online.

Comment: Looks like it's not working for me. I ended up fix it by updated the nvidia driver to version 520 and reboot.

Comment: please consider posting your fix as an answer to help others - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: built-in laptop screen not working, but external monitor working.

In my case it was caused by me executing `nvidia-xconfig` tool (following some online guide). This tool (see help) generated a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` which caused the problem after reboot. Upon restoring the original - empty - `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file, and rebooting, the problem is gone.

(posting here for future reference; should have been a comment, but too low rep to comment)